# Change variable in Ansible template based on group

Tags: templates, jinja2, ansible

I've got an Ansible inventory file a bit like this:

```
[es-masters]
host1.my-network.com

[es-slaves]
host2.my-network.com
host3.my-network.com

[es:children]
es-masters
es-slaves
```

I also have a Jinja2 template file that needs a certain value set to "true" if a host belongs to the "es-masters" group.

I'm sure that there's a simple way of doing it but after some Googling and reading the documentation, I've drawn a blank.

I'm looking for something simple and programmatic like this to go in the Jinja2 template:

```
{% if hostvars[host][group] == "es-masters" %}
node_master=true
{% else %}
node_master=false
{% endif %}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you passing hostvars to the render function or do you expect jinja2 to be able to access hostvars?

Comment: That was just an example, really - what I'm really looking for is a programmatic way to "see" the groups that a particular host is a member of and find a way to change a variable in a template based on that.

Comment: Docs: In addition to storing variables directly in the INI file, host and group variables can be stored in individual files relative to the inventory file. These variable files are in YAML format. See YAML Syntax if you are new to YAML. The YAML library is included with the AppEngine SDK

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You do it the other way around.
You check if the identifier (hostname or IP or whatever is in your inventory) is in the defined group. Not if the group is in the hostvars.

```
{% if ansible_fqdn in groups['es-masters'] %}
node_master=true
{% else %}
node_master=false
{% endif %}
```

## But, what you better should do is this:

Provide default in template

```
# role_name/templates/template.j2
node_master={{ role_name_node_master | default(true) }}
```

Than override in group_vars

```
# group_vars/es-masters.yml
role_name_node_master: false
```

Comment: How do I extend the answer with groups with children, posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955303/change-variable-in-ansible-template-based-on-group-with-children

Answer (score 10):

If your inventory does not identify hosts with ansible_fqdn, ansible_hostname, etc., you can also use `group_names` to check if the current host has "es-masters" as one of its groups.

```
{% if 'es-masters' in group_names %}
node_master=true
{% else %}
node_master=false
{% endif %}
```

See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables

Answer (score 5):

To avoid error with non existing group you should check first if the group exists:

```
{% if 'es-masters' in group_names and ansible_fqdn in groups['es-masters'] %}
node_master=true
{% else %}
node_master=false
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if ansible_fqdn in groups['es-masters'] %}
    {% set node_master=true %}
{% else %}
    {% set node_master=false %}
{% endif %}
```

maybe like this? change the var  which named `node_master`, rather than use a txt