# Change variable in Ansible template based on group with children?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I found [Change variable in Ansible template based on group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552766/change-variable-in-ansible-template-based-on-group). However how do I extend the answer in groups with children?

If I extend the group vars file in the link above to

```
[host0]
host0.my-network.com
[host1]
host1.my-network.com

[es-masters:children]
host0
host1
```

How can I extend the above post's answer (shown below) to make it work with the group vars file above? Simply putting the FQDN in the jinja2 statement does not work.

```
{% if ansible_fqdn in groups['es-masters'] %}
node_master=true
{% else %}
node_master=false
{% endif %}
```

Comment: In general, this is a structure you want to avoid. Group names shouldn't be stored in templates. Better define a variable and override this variable in group_vars.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is:
Provide default in template

```
# role_name/templates/template.j2
node_master={{ role_name_node_master | default(true) }}
```

Than override in group_vars

```
# group_vars/es-masters.yml
role_name_node_master: false
```